# master slave control of 2wd robots using xbee

Tags: arduino-leonardo, communication, xbee

Hi there I just need to ask you how I can send command from master robot to slave to follow using XBee. I have configured both the XBee in AT mode, but I totally don't have the clue how the program.

I am using the following kit components (from DF ROBOT) to build this project,

1. Romeo V2-All in one Controller (Arduino based controller).
2. Differential drive chasis with caster ball.
3. Wheel Encoders.
4. XBee 2mW PCB Antenna - Series 2 (ZigBee Mesh)  Transceiver module for the communication between two robots.
5. IR sensors.

6.Micro DC Geared Motor w/ Back Shaft (180rpm 6V).

I have done the programming for obstacle detection, positioning of robot, but I have no idea how to do the master slave programming logic.

Please help me on this. Here attached the code I have done till now:

```cpp
const int InfraredSensorPin1 = 6;//Connect the signal pin to the digital pin 6
int detected2;
int detected1;
const int InfraredSensorPin2 = 9 ; 

int E1 = 5;     //M1 Speed Control
int E2 = 6;     //M2 Speed Control
int M1 = 4;    //M1 Direction Control
int M2 = 7;    //M1 Direction Control

#define LEFT 0
#define RIGHT 1
int value;
long coder[2] = {
  0, 0
};
int lastSpeed[2] = {
  0, 0
};

void stop(void)                    //Stop
{
  digitalWrite(E1, 0);
  digitalWrite(M1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(E2, 0);
  digitalWrite(M2, LOW);
}
void advance(char a, char b)         //Move forward
{
  analogWrite (E1, a);
  digitalWrite(M1, HIGH);
  analogWrite (E2, b);
  digitalWrite(M2, HIGH);
}
void back_off (char a, char b)         //Move backward
{
  analogWrite (E1, a);
  digitalWrite(M1, LOW);
  analogWrite (E2, b);
  digitalWrite(M2, LOW);
}
void turn_L (char a, char b)            //Turn Left
{
  analogWrite (E1, a);
  digitalWrite(M1, LOW);
  analogWrite (E2, b);
  digitalWrite(M2, HIGH);
}
void turn_R (char a, char b)            //Turn Right
{
  analogWrite (E1, a);
  digitalWrite(M1, HIGH);
  analogWrite (E2, b);
  digitalWrite(M2, LOW);
}

void setup(void)
{ Serial.println("Start!");

 pinMode(InfraredSensorPin1, INPUT);
 pinMode(InfraredSensorPin2, INPUT);

advance(200,200);
  Serial.begin(19200);      //Set Baud Rate//
  attachInterrupt(LEFT, LwheelSpeed, CHANGE);    //init the interrupt mode for the digital pin 2
  attachInterrupt(RIGHT, RwheelSpeed, CHANGE);   //init the interrupt mode for the digital pin 3
}
void loop(void)
{
  if((InfraredSensorPin1==LOW&&!InfraredSensorPin2==LOW)||(InfraredSensorPin1==LOW&&InfraredSensorPin2==LOW))
  turn_L (100,100);

  else if ((InfraredSensorPin2==LOW&&!InfraredSensorPin1==LOW)||(InfraredSensorPin2==LOW&&InfraredSensorPin1==LOW))
  turn_R (100,100);

  else  
  advance (80,80);
  static unsigned long timer = 0;                //print manager timer
  if (millis() - timer > 5) {
    Serial.print("Coder value: ");
    Serial.print(coder[LEFT]);
    Serial.print("[Left Wheel] ");
    Serial.print(coder[RIGHT]);
    Serial.println("[Right Wheel]");

    lastSpeed[LEFT] = coder[LEFT];   //record the latest speed value
    lastSpeed[RIGHT] = coder[RIGHT];
    coder[LEFT] = 0;                 //clear the data buffer
    coder[RIGHT] = 0;
    timer = millis();
  }
}
void LwheelSpeed()
{
  coder[LEFT] ++;  //count the left wheel encoder interrupts
}
void RwheelSpeed()
{
  coder[RIGHT] ++; //count the right wheel encoder interrupts
}
```

Comment: You can format your code with the `{}` button in the post editor.